# Jenkins - Propagate system property to ant task

Tags: ant, jenkins, system-properties

Dos it exist a way to propagate java system property from Tomcat to jenkins ant task?
Particularly I would like to propagate `catalina.home` property to ant task. When trying `catalina.home=${catalina.home}` I get error `Property catalina.home was circularly defined.`

Comment: Have you actually access to the catalina.home variable in Jenkins? If Jenkins knows it, you can pass it on, otherwise there is no issue.

Comment: I can see catalina.home, if I display System Properties for Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

so you want `catalina.home` of the tomcat that's running jenkins passed into your ant build?
hmmm... I'm not sure it's goign to work, but try setting the `catalina.home` property to the value of the `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable:
`catalina.home=${evn.CATALINA_HOME}`

It likely won't work, you'll want to see what you set `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable is  and just pass that into your ant build:
`ant -Dcatalina.home="/usr/share/tomcat7`

Comment: `CATALINA_HOME` is not set, only system properties `catalina.home` and `catalina.base` are set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have direct access from your job configuration to your system properties. You will need to write your own plugin to read out the system properties.

Check if you have CATALINA_HOME available. If you do, pass it into ant (ant plugin has a field for that) or set it within your ant-script like thekbb suggested. `catalina.home=${evn.CATALINA_HOME}`